# Visual Studio/C#/ASP.Net Core: Build fails when adding web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

I have an ASP.Net Core project built in Visual Studio 2019. It is built as suggested in [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-asp-net-apps-with-react/) article (part "Backend"). I built the Frontend too, tested all together and everything works fine.

Now, this ASP.Net Core project has to provide Windows Authentication. Well, so I enabled IIS and Websocket Services on my Windows 10 PC (which acts as the Server system). Installed Net Core Hosting Bundle. Created an IIS Website. All as suggested in the official Microsoft Docs: [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#webconfig-file). Worked.

After that, I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authorize-users) from the official Microsoft Docs which explains how to configure Windows Authentication. Added `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`. Launched debugger settings. And now I'm stuck with the chapter "IIS" in this article. It says:

> Before publishing and deploying the project, add the following
> web.config file to the project root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Did exactly that, copy-pasted the above code. Run `Build Solution`. Build fails with following error message:

```
error CS8652: The feature 'top-level statements' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
```

... and several error messages of this kind:

```
error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
```

... every single one located in the copy-pasted `web.config` file.

How is this possible? I mean, the code must be correct or am I wrong? Since I took it from the official docs? I searched the web with no success except that the first error message is because the project seems to use a preview of the new C# version. Even though I never set the project to use this language version ...

If I delete the `web.config`, the build works. But this isn't really useful since I want to publish my project into a folder and access the IIS website. And this is only possible with `web.config` file.

So I am brand new to C# and have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Usually I do Frontend stuff. I hope my question is not too stupid and someone can help me.

Here is the Project structure. You can see the `web.config` file at the root of the project. "IIS Folder" is the Folder I want the project publish into. The files inside are from the last build.

[image]

Comment: CS errors are for C# so it sounds like it is trying to compile your web.config as a C# file. Could it be that you accidently named your file web.config.cs or something?

Comment: Karl-Johan Sjörgen, thanks for your help. I think the file is named correctly. Added an image of the project structure.

Comment: In the preferences of the web.config file (right click > preferences) what does it say for `Build Action`?

Comment: Jay Fridge, thank you for your answer! It says "C# Compiler" - Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Change that to `Content` and try again.

Comment: Jay Fridge Works like a charm! Thank you! However, when I choose .editorconfig file, it also works. Why is that? Is it okay that it works with this configuration as well?

Comment: What do you mean with "when you choose .editorconfig file"? Choose it where?

Comment: Jay Fridge, in the dropdown for `Build Action`, there is also a possibility to choose `editorconfig file`, besides `Content`, `C# Compiler` etc. :)

Comment: Really? Interesting :) The only information i can find for Build Actions is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019). As you can see every action does something slightly different. But for the web.config `Content` seems to be the best fit.

Comment: Jay Fridge Thanks a lot for your help. You saved my day :)